# How to Create a new DataSet?

Tags: java, arrays, copy

So I am given this assignment to write a class that does some number calculations, the client passes an array of random double numbers to Dataset. And well everything depends on me getting this part of the program right. But to be honest I haven't got the faintest idea of what to do here.

```
//Instance Data
private double[] data;

 //Constructor: Create a new DataSet
 // Parameter : data points to be included into this DataSet
 // Exception : the number of data points must be at least 2

public DataSet(double[] data)
{  


}
```

Comment: Save the parameter into the instance variable, if there are more than two numbers in the array, else throw an exception?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private double[] data;  

//As you throw a exception inside your method (constructor in this case)
//you need to declare the 'throws Exception' clause, so you have to 
//catch this exception when you create a new instance of DataSet.
public DataSet(double[] _data) throws Exception
{  
   //Your comment says 'the number of data points must be at least 2'
   //you accomplish this by checking its size.
   if(_data.length < 2) {
       //As it say exception I assume in this case you want to throw a exception
       //you accomplish this like the following           
       throw new Exception("the number of data points must be at least 2");
   }
   //"Save the parameter into the instance variable"
   //It's pretty clear to me what "t0mppa" said. Read again please...
   this.data = _data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't totally get why it works but it does!

Comment: I added explanations to the code step by step, I hope you get it now, cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I mean I kinda got the beginning stuff in the code, and the if statement. That is clear to me. What is not so clear is why this.data = data; works Since data is an array, and to be honest i don't quite grasp how copying an array works outside of creating a for loop and passing each value index by index. You can tell i am pretty new to this, but thank you for the help.